# PCA scores vs. Varimax-rotated PCA scores

Tags: r, prcomp

I have performed PCA using `prcomp` in R with my databases of 75-76 indicator variables and 7232 companies, including NAs. Before applying the function, I centred my data, but did not rescale them because they are all indicator variables. (Is my reasoning correct?)

After that I `varimax`-rotated the loadings of the 2 or 3 first principal components following the instructions by *amoeba* [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59213/how-to-compute-varimax-rotated-principal-components-in-r).

Since I had centred, but not rescaled my data, I changed the code to:

```
Varimax_results <- varimax(rawLoadings,normalize = FALSE)
invLoadings     <- t(pracma::pinv(VarimaxLoadings))
scores          <- scale(DatosPCA, scale = FALSE) %*% invLoadings
```

Now I am trying to figure out why the scores given by "prcomp" and the scores obtained using the code above are not the same.

I am probably missing some theoretical background, so I would be grateful if someone could tell me if the scores are supposed to be the same and, in that case, what I am doing wrong in my code. If they are not supposed to be the same, which ones should I use?

Thank you very much!